# Pass aspx form value to aspx.cs variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you pass an aspx form value to aspx.cs variable. 
When I am on page 1 and select item 1, I'd like the value of PROC1 to be sent to the next page. I don't know how to accept it.

**aspx form (page1.aspx)**

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a name</option>
  <option value="PROC1">item 1</option>
  <option value="PROC2">item 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**receiving c# class (page2.aspx)**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      // I want to know how to capture the value of PROC1 
      // so I can use it as a variable on this new page
 }
```

Comment: You can do cross page postbacks or you can pass the data via query string (it might be easier if you switch to Web Server Controls instead of plain HTML). No doubt someone will recommend cookies or Session, but those are generally a bad idea for passing data between pages since the user may have more than one page open at any given time.

Comment: Because you reference aspx and aspx.cs I assume you're doing WebForms development. Why not just make it a server-side control and then you can access the properties of the object in your code behind without have to mess with the Request.Form collection. That would be using the tool more in the way it's intended/designed.

Comment: You can use `Query String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to give your form element a `name` attribute.  This is the "key" in the key/value pairs that forms send to the server:

```
<select name="someSelect">
```

Then when this form posts to a page, you can access the form values in the `Request` object on that page:

```
var selectedValue = Request.Form["someSelect"];
```